# Copy everything except image and span Tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I try to copy everythin exceptthe image and span Tag.
At the moment the script copying the image tag, too.
How can I use the

XLST

```
<xsl:when test="child::img[@src='note.png']">  
   <note>
      <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::span[@class='mark'][not(preceding-sibling::span[@class='mark'])])]"/>
      </p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::ul]/node()"/>
  </note>        
</xsl:when>
```

XML Source

```
<note>
  <p>
    <img src="note.png"/>
    <span class="mark">Text</span>
    Text
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li><p>Text</p></li>
    <li><p>Text</p></li>
  </ul>
</note>
```

XML Targed

```
<note>
  <p>
    Text
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li><p>Text</p></li>
    <li><p>Text</p></li>
  </ul>
</note>
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="child::img[@src='note.png']">  
           <p>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::span[@class='mark'])][not(self::img[@src='note.png'])]"/>
           </p>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Or **

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::span[@class='mark'])]
                                      [not(self::img[@src='note.png'])]"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**OutPut:**

```
<note>
<p>
   Text
</p>
<ul>
  <li>
     <p>Text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
     <p>Text</p>
  </li>
</ul>
</note>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general if you want to do such transformations then you start with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and then add empty templates matching the nodes to be removed e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="img | span"/>
```

or perhaps

```
<xsl:template match="img | span[@class = 'mark']"/>
```

if only span elements with that class should be removed.